# Do aliens need to invade humans?

Tags: warfare, space-colonization, earth, space-warfare

Everything has gravity, even the smallest things.

NASA and ESA considered using drones and rockets rotating around asteroids to to pull them away with their gravity in order to avoid apocalyptic level collisions.

The problem being that like in the case of **2019 OK** sometimes researches find asteroids when they are already ''too close''. A lot of near-deaths pass unnoticed around our planet.

With this incredible simplicity aliens would only need to pull a few hundred asteroids in trajectory towards earth and blackmail humanity into slavery if they wanted those asteroids to go away.

Another example would be aliens using their spaceships as artificial moons to create massive tsunamis and drown the planet or maybe simply turn all major cities to dust with huge mirrors, like a kid burning ants with a piece of glass.

And I'm pretty sure even aliens had their version of Sun Tzu

So given the simplicity of winning planetary wars without ever stepping foot in another planet, is there ever a reason why aliens would invade another planet by landing with military forces?

Comment: Would depend on what the Aliens want from the humans. And how good we are at pretending we're not home.

Comment: You have correctly intuited the fundamental principle that if the technological gap is too large, then the weaker belligerent does not stand a chance.Yes, Spain conquered Mexico and Peru. Yes, the British ruled India. Yes, the Dutch ruled Malaysia. Yes, a tiny British force defeated the gigantic Chinese Empire. As a consequence, in your story make certain that the opposing forces are sufficiently well balanced to allow for drama, thrill and suspense.

Comment: @user535733 a colonial free work force still might be a reason, pay them nothing and they build rockets to deliver materials and tools into space, ready to be catched by the aliens.

Comment: If aliens need to blackmail humans, they are probably bluffing and _don't_ want to actually use force that is so lethal.

Comment: I won't Answer because it would be redundant with existing, good answers. I will, however, strongly recommend [The Course of Empire](https://www.baen.com/the-course-of-empire.html) (read online or free download, no registration!), which needed to address exactly this question. (It's also one of the best premises I've ever seen. "Twenty years ago, the Jao invaded Earth. We lost."  Nota bene, you will enjoy the book more if you DON'T read the spoilerific cover blurb.)

Comment: @AlexP: In at least a couple of those cases (Mexico & India) it wasn't so much a case of the Europeans conquering the natives by outright military force, but of using diplomacy.  E.g. Cortez didn't conquer the Aztecs with just his small force of Spaniards, he mobilized the other local states to revolt against the hated Aztecs.  (Who were, despite historical revisionism, not nice people at all.)

Comment: @jamesqf: Diplomacy **is** technology. The Europeans came from a world with a history of thousands of years of experience in wheeling and dealing, in using trade as well as force to achieve goals, and so on. Moreover, the Europeans came from a world where all this stuff had been written down and studied for thousands of years. There was nothing stopping the Tlaxcalans from forging a wide alliance against the Aztecs on their own before Cortez came, but they just didn't have the mental equipment and know-how. One should not underestimate the historical importance of Aristotle, Seneca, Cicero &c.

Comment: To support/add to AlexP's comment - just yesterday was watching some youtube video in which one was presented as member of hunter gatherer tribe(can't confirm, but maybe probably, but I'll buy it). He was asked - what are most important things in life - his answer is meat, honey. Then a more fresh yound guy/mind was involved(a geek) and the list was extended by recognising importance of water. Those guys aren't stupid, it just that shoulders of giants are extreamly important.

Comment: @AlexP: It's not so much that the Aztec's subject tribes (or FTM people in the various Indian states) didn't understand diplomacy, it's that (quite simplistically) all of the parties wanted to be the leader, and wouldn't accept playing second fiddle to any of the others.  But they could all accept the Spanish, given their "alien" appearance & technology.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, these aliens *could* just destroy every major population centre from orbit, and conquer Earth that way, but... what would be left for them to conquer? A lifeless planet full of destroyed infrastructure that they may not even understand how to use anyway? Why would they want that? Sure, there are plenty of resources they could extract, but they'd have to do it themselves because they killed off any locals they could have forced to do it for them.

A ground war is still going to cause a lot of damage, especially if it's being fought on a global scale, and it's probably going to take a while. But it's still a *lot* more surgical than just pelting Earth with asteroids or "rods from God" or giant *Independence Day* laser beams or whatever. They'll be able to pick and choose who and what they destroy, in order to cripple Earth's resistance while ensuring that, by the end of their conquest, they'll still be left with an inhabitable planet filled with infrastructure, resources, and - most importantly - sentient lifeforms, all of which they can then readily exploit.

And let's face it, if they have the technology to pelt us with asteroids or build spaceships large enough to create tsunamis in the first place, then we're probably not going to stand much of a chance against them in a ground war, either.

Comment: Personally I'd of thought that sterilization of a planet is the first step to terraforming the planet for habitation.

Answer (score 5):

### Only Aliens Who Value Conservation over Imperialism Can Solve for the Fermi Paradox

Need is such a strong word: no alien civilization needs to attack Earth at all.  The better question is, would it be in the nature of an alien race we encounter to attack Earth in one way over the other?  Predicting the nature of alien life sounds random and unpredictable, but science has one tool that actually informs us a bit about what qualities an advanced alien race would need to be selectively fit enough to become an interstellar species.

The [Fermi Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) is the assertion that if there is intelligent life in the universe capable of interstellar travel, then we should have been able to prove its existence by now unless there is some Great Filter.  The 3 most common solutions to the Great Filter problem are that intelligent aliens will typically wipe themselves out through over-consumption (The Easter Island filter), they will wipe themselves out in a Nuclear War (The MAD filter), or that intelligent aliens have chosen not to make themselves known to humanity (the hidden filter).

If you follow the assumption that Fermi's Paradox must be resolved in a way that alien neighbors do exist, then it means that if a warlike alien race existed nearby then they should have already attacked us by now, or fallen victim to their own MAD. So, instead we should start from the assumption that our interstellar neighbors are not violent, are staying hidden, and value conservation highly enough to avoid the Easter Island filter.

We humans are relatively bad at conservation, and yet we have chosen to protect about 17% of our land mass.  Most of these area are set aside because there is something that lives there that we humans find interesting.  An endangered species, cool looking predator's, useful plant life, etc.  So, if aliens need to be better at conservation than humans to solve the Easter Island Filter, it means that they are likely choosing to set aside a large number of planets they find as nature reserves because it must be in their nature to conserve.  So, when such an alien species finds Earth, they will ask themselves very seriously, "Is there something interesting that lives here worth saving?" before they try to colonize it.

It is hard to know how a conservationist alien species would think, but we humans tend to prioritize an animal's coolness factor very highly; so, if conservation minded aliens find Earth, seeing some privative tool using creatures could rouse the interest of their conservationist community. So, they would feel compelled to let us live in peace and go to one of the other 300 million or more inhabitable planets in our galaxy to plant their next colony while their cloaked ships full of nature documentary crews watch us from above.  Thus, solving the Fermi Paradox.

### So why would they come out of hiding and attack us at all?

The most probable reason such a species would come out of hiding and attack us now after having stayed hidden for so long is to help us survive.  As humans continue to spread threatening all life on Earth, the aliens view of humanity may shift from a species in need of protection to a species in need of population control.  If they just rained indiscriminate death down on our planet, they would be further damaging the world they are trying to protect which makes no since.

Instead, they decide to cull the human race to ensure that their great-great-great-grand-children can grow up in a galaxy that still has humans in it.  So, from our perspective, we have found ourselves  at war with an alien race, But, to the aliens, it is just open hunting season on humans and their government has issued 50 million hunting licenses to help keep us from starving ourselves the same way we do with deer in areas where their natural predators have been wiped out.

While I am not saying it is impossible for us to encounter an alien species that wants to destroy us from orbit, it is rather highly improbable to meet such an alien civilization that would consider that course of action simply on the grounds that our planet has not been assaulted by such an alien threat so far... at least not in last 65 million years or so.

Comment: I agree with your likelihood of motivations.  I focused more on the physical reasons to not invade.  I do like the idea of a hunting license.  Though, a bio weapon may be more efficient.

Comment: @ShadoCat Yes, but bioweapons can be unpredictable.  While humans like to blow shit up and hope for the best, a less violent more conservationist race would need much greater assurances than we would that killings happen in a controlled manner.  A perfectly engineered bio weapon could mutate and kill way too many humans, or jump species and wipe chimpanzees out of existence, or we could just quarantine and wipe out it out in 2 weeks... or so you would think... An invasion could mean aliens vaporizing hospitals, retirement communities, and politicians to strengthen our herd.

Comment: I can see that.  I was just thinking of the easiest way to get the job done without letting the world know that someone did it.

Answer (score 4):

One word Occupation.

True you could destroy earth without a army but holding earth is another matter all together.

Ofcourse how the question is Why would an an alien race want to occupy earth anyway.

1. ideology or religion.  It's possible that The Invasion of Earth might be the alien's way of aggressively spreading there  Religion or ideology to other species. In this case occupation with an army makes much more sense Then Just bombing  from beyond orbit  Since every human you kill is one less convert to your religion or ideology.
2. Is galactic law. If there is one group aliens out there there is a good chance there are more.  Is there probably going going to feel uncomfortable having genocide neighbors.  If that's the case it's possible that the aliens may not want to glass Earth because because of purely galactic political reasons.
3. Glory.
   If the alien race is really so far more advanced than us it's for advanced and us that it's possible it's possible that it sees war with us is more of a game than anything else. In which case Fighting us on a little bit of a level playing field may be seen as more fun or more challenging than just bombing from beyond orbit.

Comment: 4:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Needs_Women

Answer (score 4):

No, aliens do not need to invade [earth].

They can nuke us from orbit (It's the only way to be sure), they can melt us with their space-lasers, they can ignore us and never even show themselves (current option).

They only need to invade us if they operate under a specific set of objectives, ie. if they feel they need to control earth and for some reason do not want to kill a majority of humans or make a major percentage of useable surface area uninhabitable.

Answer (score 3):

**No, aliens do not need to invade the Earth.**

The very simple reason is that anything they want to get from the Earth, they can get from the Asteroid Belt or Oort Cloud and not have to deal with a huge gravity well and annoying people who don't want you to take their stuff.

Also, lobbing rocks from the high ground is much cheaper than training troops.  Just destroy anything that can launch a vehicle from the Earth's surface to orbit.  If they have high enough tech to have FTL travel, nothing we have is a threat to them.  Even if we launch a nuke, they would have minutes to shoot it down or get out if its way (assuming they don't just tank the blast).

Comment: Nukes don't work so well in the vacuum of space either.

Comment: I could think of several reasons to invade Earth.  Spread ideology,  To eliminate a possible threat, to   Aquire a habitable planet that needs no terraforming.

Comment: @Thorne Yeah.  Much better to use it to pump lasers but we'd use what we have.

Comment: @BryanMcClure But would it be habitable for *them*?  Also, I'm of the mind that if you want more habitable territory, you can just build it and avoid the gravity well.  Ideology?  Maybe.  Just take over the airwaves and let people grow up only hearing your story. Or approach in peace and offer goods and ideas that promote their ideology.  Much more efficient.  Threat?  Rocks from space.

Comment: @shadocat  Even if most of the nation lived in space habitats  There's gonna be a small percent of the population that would still prefer a planet.  Even if this is only.00000 1%  In a galactic Empire that could be easily be a couple billion people.

Comment: @BryanMcClure Unless they are so technologically advanced that we can't touch them with our weapons, I just really can't see the point.  Besides, I can't see us not using enough nukes to destroy any environment that they would hope to gain.

Answer (score 2):

They believe that no other sapient species should be allowed but destroying non-sapient life (even non-sapient individuals of otherwise sapient species - e.g. comatose patients in the hospital) is also not allowed. You're going to have a very difficult time threading that needle without invading.

Answer (score 2):

As a demonstration of their understanding of the galactic rules of civilized combat.

Space is big and old...

When you come across a planet full of egotistical primates who are just begging to be conquered, you can assume that they are exactly as they appear, a independent and lonely "Kardashev Zero Point Who Cares?" group of soon-to-be slaves with no potential for resisting your K-2 awesomeness.

...or...

Since you've already survived long enough to crawl up to K-2 level, you might pause and consider other possibilities.

- Maybe this little world is an experiment being run by those K-6 crabs over in Andromeda.
- Maybe they are like the Knox, so advanced that K scale doesn't apply,
  yet wise enough to hide their technology such that each new less-advanced species they encounter is unintimidated and free to expose its moral character during initial contact.
- Maybe your target planet is a lost (but still loved) colony of those K-infinite ascended apes who check in with our universe occasionally from their
  higher plains of existence.

Maybe you should show a little respect before you assume that every apparently primitive civilization is yours to pillage and enslave.  At the very least, show enough respect to give them a fighting chance at whatever pitiful level of combat they are capable of.

You say they can barely get into orbit?  Well then, you better take the battle down to them, where they can at least resist.  Then if their transcendent precursors happen to check in to see how their ignorant step children are doing, at least you can say that you treated them with fairness.  If your lucky, those precursors will treat you with the same respect and not just make all of your suns go supernova simultaneously.